# Fine Uploader - objectProperties - Key

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have 1 page whick give to user add new car to his cars collection.
User MUST to add minimum 1 image to this car item.

In AWS S3 service I save images in this path architecture:

bucket_name/cars/HERE_IS_USER_ID/HERE_IS_CAR_ID/and here photos

I use fine uploader.
ANd If i do add car in 2 step - all is going good

In 1 step I add to my database car - and send from server side userId and new car Id.
And then in step 2 I init Fine uploader with this id:

Below Code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('cars.services.fineUploader', ['ngResource'])
        .factory('FineUploader', ['$resource', '$http', 'AppConfig', function ($resource, $http, AppConfig) {
            return function (divId, templateName, autoUpload, foldersBtn, uploadSuccessCallback, type, parentId, id) {
                var key = '';
                var keyExist = false;
                getKey();

                if (!qq.supportedFeatures.folderSelection) {
                    document.getElementById(foldersBtn).style.display = "none";
                }
                var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
                    element: document.getElementById(divId),
                    template: templateName,
                    autoUpload: autoUpload,
                    request: {
                        endpoint: 'carsbucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
                        accessKey: 'ACCESS',
                    },
                    extraButtons: [
                  {
                      element: document.getElementById(foldersBtn),
                      folders: true
                  }
                    ],
                    signature: {
                        endpoint: AppConfig.apiUrl + 'api/AmazonS3/GetSignature'
                    },
                    uploadSuccess: {
                        endpoint: uploadSuccessCallback()
                    },
                    iframeSupport: {
                        localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
                    },
                    objectProperties: {
                        key: function (id) {
                            var fileName = uploader.getName(id);
                            var ext = qq.getExtension(fileName);
                            return key+ '/' + fileName + "." + ext;
                        }
                    }
                });
                return {

                    Uploader: function () {
                        return uploader;
                    },
                    StartUpload: function () {
                        uploader.uploadStoredFiles();
                    },
                    InitUploader: function () {

                        while (!keyExist) {
                            getKey();
                        }
                    }

                };
                function getKey() {
                    var itemRequest = {
                        "ItemType": type,
                        "ParentId": parentId,
                        "ItemId": id
                    };
                    $http.post("http://localhost:42309/api/AmazonS3/GetItemKey", itemRequest).success(function (data, status) {
                        key = data;
                        keyExist = true;
                    });
                }
            }

        }]);
})();
```

And this is code how I init this service:

```
  function Uploader(shopId, shopItemId) {
                    vm.step = 2;
                    uploader = FineUploader('s3FU', 'qq-template-gallery', false, 'foldersButton', testCallback, 1, shopId, shopItemId);



                }
```

Now I want to do all ADD ITEM logic in 1 step
But I dont know how do it - because I need init FineUploader - but I dont have carId and UserId

.........

Comment: Why don't you just continue using the workflow that is working? Seems like you are leaving out some details here, so I do t really know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Because I want to make - Easy way for create new item
And to do second step only for Add items - not really good i think

Comment: Seems like you are leaving out some details here, so I dont really know what you are trying to accomplish. Not seeing a problem with whatever approach you are using now. If you want to get input from the user before uploading, then you are free to do that.